# Can't create linked server - sql server and mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I want to create a linked server between SQL Server and a MySQL instance. I followed the steps outlined in [this tutorial](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql) but it's not working. I've recorded a video of the process I am using to create the server:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8psvDjysHk&feature=youtu.be
```

SQL server return this error:

> *The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?*
>
> *An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)*
>
> *The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MYSQLAPP" reported an error. Authentication failed.
>
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MYSQLAPP".
>
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MYSQLAPP" returned message "Invalid authorization specification". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)*

Comment: It was very helpful to include the video. I followed the steps here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx and they worked fine for me. I didn't see you restarting the SQL-Server instance in your video - so maybe you should try this.

Comment: i followed the steps on your link, but my problem doesn't resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SYSTEM DSN on the SQL Server machine but in your video you create a USER DSN. Select the System tab in the ODBC applet before you create the DSN.

Comment: now i want to sync my data with mysql but i don't know what to do , please help me for this work